# How to access database from Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Import/Exporting databases from one machine to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2288621/import-exporting-databases-from-one-machine-to-another)

I am on Ubuntu. I can access files (phpmyadmin folder) in xampp (I used it in Windows). What files do I need to copy from xampp or maybe there is .sql file somewhere, so I could copy database which was in Windows and use it on Ubuntu (I have already installed LAMP in Ubuntu). Thanks.

Comment: @hakre: It's really not duplicate, because I can't access Windows, I need to do that in Ubuntu. Please, don't close it.

Comment: The problem is OS agnostic. Use phpmyadmin or the mysql commandline tools to create and import database dumps.

Answer (score 1):

it's this folder

> C:\xampp\mysql\data

but as far as i know it won't work , the best this todo is to login to the windows and export it to .sql files

Comment: Can't login to Windows directly.

Comment: so try to move this folder from the xampp to the lamp

Comment: all the folder is the mysql now look at lamp and find mysql folder should be data folder over there too so paste and overwrite all...